# Email using Singleton pattern

Tags: java, singleton

I have a webapp running on my server, which does some *balance* update. Once the *balance* is updated, I need to check if the *balance* is below 5000. In case, the *balance* goes below 5000, I should **send an email alert**. The point to note here is that, I need to send the alert **only once in a day**, alert should not keep going every time the balance is below 5000.
I believe, I should use singleton pattern for sending the mail, but I am not sure how to use this.
The program when sees the *balance* going below 5000, should call the singleton class which will have the function to send email alert, but how do you ensure that program will not call this function again when the balance goes down?
Can anyone guide me on this?

Comment: Please try something using below answers and if you face any problem try to get help.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two separate things you need think about:

- Email sending service.

Several ways to implement it. Yes, it could be **Singleton**, but it also could be a plain Java service. If you use **Spring**, then they have very simple and useful predefined implementations. Here is an [example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/07/java-mail-spring-gmail-smtp.html).

- Your checking balance logic.

Depends on what you really need. If you need to check every balance update but send alerts not more that once per day, then it will be something like:

```
    private Date lastAlertDate;

    private static final BALANCE_LIMIT = 5000;

    private void handleBalanceUpdated(long balance) {
        if (balance < 5000) {
        log.info("Balance has gone below {}", BALANCE_LIMIT);
        int daysDifference = getDifferenceInDays(lastAlertDate, new Date());
        if (daysDifference >= 1) {
            log.info("Last alert was {} days ago, going to send email alert", daysDifference);
            alertService.sendSimpleAlert("Balance has gone below " + BALANCE_LIMIT + "!");
            lastAlertDate = new Date();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but it means that after every alert I have to update the database with this lastAlertDate. Could I try using Singleton here in some manner?

Comment: It depends on what kind of component you use for this "checker". It can simply 'live' in the memory in your system (e.g. as a listener) and store reference to latest date. You don't need DB at this case.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton is a design pattern that makes sure only one instance of an object is created.

Doesn't sound like it has anything to do with what you need, you could add a flag in your DB like `alert_sent=true/false` and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

[User Timer Task to send mail only once a day](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

[Singleton Pattern](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/singleton-pattern/)

Comment: But then it will send the alert every day to the same user until the balance goes up.

Comment: User those logic work as a Task and if you want to change you can.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any "special" design patterns here. For instance you can store the date when the last email notification was sent, like:

```
Date lastEmail = ... // last email date
```

And when trying to send email chekc the condition:

```
If( ... ) // lastEmail is before current day
{  //send emal and update lastEmail }
```